# Insert bitmap to sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have code for inserting Bitmap to sqlite database below. If I put byte[] object into content values the query insert is unsuccessful, it returns -1, but if I comment on the line `cv.put(CagTablePictures.CAG_FIELD_PICTURE, byteArray);`, the insert is success. Where is the mistake? thanks.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(CagTablePictures.CAG_FIELD_NAME, "Bitmap_" + n);
cv.put(CagTablePictures.CAG_FIELD_PICTURE, byteArray);
long id = mDatabase.insert(CAGLayerManager.CAG_TABLE_PICTURES, null, cv);
```

Comment: CAG_FIELD_PICTURE field type is Blob?

Comment: yes @RodionAltshuler... the field is BLOB

Comment: oh..I find the problem, it is my mistake, the column CagTablePictures.CAG_FIELD_PICTURE not created in table due to spelling error..

Answer (score 0):

Just an easy Alternative You can use SqliteMaestro software to create databases with bitmap in them